# TinyMCE Text Editor ; Display all html tags on post including <html><body> & all that

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce-4

Model:

```
public class MyEditor
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [AllowHtml]
    [UIHint("tinymce_classic")]                                        
    public string PageContents { get; set; }         
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult TinyEditor(MyEditor OBJ)
{
    var obj = OBJ.PageContents;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 

    }
    return View(OBJ);
}
```

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PageContents)                                         
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PageContents)
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>        
}
```

> Problem : On Post , Model gets all html tags like below. Why it's
>   taking all tags of html page

:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> </head> <body> <p>Hello</p> <p><img
src="http://www.my.org/content/img/4.jpg" alt="" width="50"
height="50" /></p> </body> </html>
```